# Integral inequality and the Hölder inequality

Tags: integration, functions, inequality, holder-inequality

*Let $\mu:S\rightarrow[0, +\infty]$ be a positive measure on $S$ $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ such that $\mu(X)=1$, and let be $f,g:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be positive $S$-measurable functions such that:
$$f(x)g(x)\geq1$$
$\mu$-almost everywhere in $X$.
Prove that:
$$\int_X f d\mu\cdot\int_X gd\mu\geq1$$*
So, I've proved that $\int_X f(x)g(x)d\mu\geq1$ and then I used the Hölder inequality and obtained:
$$\left(\int_X f^2 d\mu\right)^{\frac12}\cdot\left(\int_X g^2d\mu\right)^{\frac12}\geq1.$$
How do I move forward from this point?

Comment: English note:  "prove", not "proove".  TeX note:  only symbols intended to be set in a math font should be set in math mode; for example, "$S$ $\sigma$-algebra" `$S$ $\sigma$-algebra` (or, even better, "$S$ a $\sigma$-algebra") instead of "‍‍$S\ \sigma-algebra$" `$S\ \sigma-algebra$`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice. Writing "only symbols intended to be set in a math font should be set in math mode" might be misinterpreted and lead to the other extreme that is often seen where only math symbols are enclosed in `$`: `$\int$ f d$\mu$`

Comment: @md2perpe, I meant to include $f$ in [your example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401572/integral-inequality-and-the-h%c3%b6lder-inequality#comment9207694_4401572) $\int f\,\mathrm d\mu$ as a symbol (that happens to be a letter!) that should be set in math mode—and arguably even the $\mathrm d$, as a symbol that should be set in math mode but (I but not everyone believe) using `\mathrm`—but I agree it could easily be interpreted otherwise.  Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @LSpice. I understood what you meant. I was just a bit worried that your wordings would be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $t \mapsto 1/t$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$ Jensen's inequality gives
$$
\frac{1}{\int_X f d\mu} \le \int_X \frac{1}{f} d\mu.
$$
From this inequality and $g \ge 1/f$ a.e. we get
$$
\int_X f d\mu\int_X g d\mu \ge \int_X f d\mu\int_X \frac{1}{f} d\mu \ge 1
$$

Edit: A way to use Cauchy Schwarz instead of Jensen's inequality:
Since $\sqrt{fg} \ge 1$ a.e. we have
$$
1=\int_X 1 d\mu \le \int_X\sqrt{f}\sqrt{g} d\mu \le (\int_X f d\mu)^{1/2} (\int_X g d\mu)^{1/2}.  
$$
Squaring this inequality leads to the desired result.

Comment: Is there any way to prove this without using the Jensen's inequality?

Comment: I don't see any other way (which does not mean that there isn't one). At least, I think Cauchy Schwarz is not suitable to prove this inequality since i.g. $\int_X f d\mu < (\int_X f^2 d\mu)^{1/2}$ (and the same for $g$), so you can't go to the inequality you want from there.

Comment: I was asking because the hint for the solution is to use the Holder inequality, so I tried to use that, but I don't see how it cluld come in handy.

Comment: I edited the answer. Indeed one can use Cauchy Schwarz.